# AWS S3 object lifecycle through Boto

Tags: python, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, boto

How does one manage an S3 object's lifecycle through boto?

I can't find anything related to that subject in the [API documentation](http://readthedocs.org/docs/boto/en/latest/ref/).

Comment: can you be a bit more specific about what you mean by "lifecycle". Do you want to manage how long an object will live until its deleted? Do you just want to know *how* to delete something with boto? etc.. etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The S3 lifecycle API is barely a month old and the code wasn't even added to boto until after you posted this question.  The code is there now though and if you grab it, you can run pydoc on the code and look at the documentation:

```
% git clone https://github.com/boto/boto.git
% cd boto/boto
% pydoc -w ./
% open s3.lifecycle.html
```